# Show all image from post meta wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show all image from meta data to my wordpress, but just showing one image..
below is my code

```
  <?php

      $attachment_ids= get_post_meta( $post_id, 'slidephoto', true );
      foreach((array)$attachment_ids AS $attachment_id){
      echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_ids, 'medium');
    }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently echoing the array, where as you need to echo the single id (the second part of the foreach). Also depending on how the values have been saved in the database, as one post meta per id, or as one post meta holds an array of id's you might want to change the third parameter to false.

Edit: If this is still failing try doing a:

```
var_dump( $post_id );die();
```

before the code below and make sure the id is correct, if it is you could then do a:

```
var_dump( $attachment_ids );die();
```

And comment the result of both.

```
$attachment_ids = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'slidephoto', true );
foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ){
      echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'medium');
}
```

Edit after `var_dump` results: Ok, Looks like the ids are not being saved correctly, if you have no control over how the id's are saved then give this ago.

```
$attachment_ids = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'slidephoto', true );
$attachment_ids= explode(',', $attachment_ids);
foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ){
      echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'medium');
}
```

Alternatively if you do make sure you are saving the id's as an array the you wont need the explode.

Comment: @TaufiqHidayah Could you try the edited code, and comment what it returns please.

Comment: string(39) "3569,3568,3512,3501,3500,3473,3465,3402" like this .. for var_dump( $attachment_ids );die();
and 
int(3585) for       var_dump( $post_id );die();

Comment: @TaufiqHidayah Check out the updated, code. Should be working for you now.

Comment: BTW can you tell me why ? :D

Comment: Your post meta was saved as a comma separated string instead of an array. The php explode function turns strings in to arrays, the first parameter just tells explode what the array values are separated by in your string. So, in the example above, at every comma take the next value and add it to the array as another value. 


If you're still confused by this function, I suggest checking out the php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php